# Loop through dataframe to create new variable

Tags: r, loops, mutate

I am trying to come up with a way to loop through a data frame and recognise points shared between 2 columns and work iteratively to assign a unique factor to these. Specifically, I have a data frame indicating points along a river and which points are immediately upstream of this.

Here is some example data:

```
df <- data.frame(RiverID = rep(c(1,2), each = 15), SiteID = rep((c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,13,13,13)),2),
                 Upstream_SiteID = rep((c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)),2),
                 Dist2Mouth = rep((c(2000,2000,2000,1500,1500,1500,1500,1000,1000,1000,1000,500,500,500,500)),2))
```

And the basic paint image below might help explain the kind of data I have.

[image]

What I would like to do is identify all possible 'routes' through the system (orange letters in the image). So in the example, I would start from point 13, go 'upstream' in the dataframe (i.e. lower Distance2Mouth values) and recognise 4 different routes (A-D). I then need to iteratively keep working up the data frame and assign routes to each point.

There are some instances where the stretch of river between the two points could belong to two routes. For example in the image below, the section between 2-1 could be part of routes C or D. In these instances, I would like to create multiple rows with the same SiteID and Upstream_SiteID that list the different potential routes.

Lastly, I have these instances across various rivers, so I would like to loop through the dataframe and apply the above code for each RiverID.

Desired output (the correct routes apply to RiverID '1'):

```
output <- data.frame(RiverID = rep(c(1,2), each = 16),
             SiteID = rep((c(2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,13,13,13)),2),
             Upstream_SiteID = rep((c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)),2),
             Dist2Mouth = rep((c(2000,2000,2000,2000,1500,1500,1500,1500,1000,1000,1000,1000,500,500,500,500)),2),
             Route = as.factor(c(rep(c("D","C","B","A"),times = 4),rep(c("H","G","F","E"),times = 4))))
```

Comment: This is a graph theory problem. You should have a look at the `igraph` package.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Although the data origin is graphical, within R it is very much a data coding problem. Recognising points shared in SiteID and the UpstreamID, looping through this etc. I just don't know how to implement it

Comment: I don't mean graphical as in you drew a picture of it. I mean [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory). There are highly efficient algorithms to solve this ready for you in the `igraph` package. You want a list of all the paths connecting Node 13 to Node 1 through the directed graph defined in your data frame.

Comment: Sounds interesting thank you! I'm still hoping there'll be a data coding alternative within R too (fingers crossed)

Comment: `igraph` is an R package. I don't know it well--I don't know exactly which function to use (and I don't have time today to reasearch it), but this is probably 4 or 5 lines of R code if the first line is `library(igraph)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`igraph` is definitely the right tool for problems like this. However, it is also possible to do what you need with a few lines of code without the package. The routes are identified by the `go_up()` function which uses a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm.

```r
## Builds a nested list with all possible paths on its deepest level
#
#  path  path so far
#  ups   list of upstream points for each point
#
go_up <- function(path, ups) {
  
  # last point of the path
  last <- tail(path, 1)  
  if (last %in% names(ups)) {
    
    # continue with all possible upstream points
    lapply(ups[[as.character(last)]], 
           function(up) go_up(c(path, up), ups))
    
    # finish if no upstream point exists
  } else paste(path, collapse='---') 
      # path is collapsed into a string so that the resulting list can be
      #   easily flattened
}
```

This can be then applied to each river separately like this:

```r
river.routes <- lapply(split(df, df$RiverID), function(river) {
  
  # list with upstream points for each point
  ups <- tapply(river$Upstream_SiteID, river$SiteID, c)
  # we will start from the highest ID
  last <- max(river$SiteID)
  # find the routes
  routes <- go_up(last, ups)
  # flatten the list and split the routes into points
  routes <- strsplit(unlist(routes), '---')
  
  # add a logical column for each route
  for (i in seq_along(routes)) {
    river[[paste0('route', i)]] <- river$SiteID %in% routes[[i]]
  }
  
  river
})
```

Output:

```r
river.routes
# $`1`
#    RiverID SiteID Upstream_SiteID Dist2Mouth route1 route2 route3 route4
# 1        1      2               1       2000   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
# 2        1      3               1       2000  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
# 3        1      4               1       2000  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
# 4        1      5               2       1500   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# 5        1      6               2       1500  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
# 6        1      7               3       1500  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
# 7        1      8               4       1500  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
# 8        1      9               5       1000   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# 9        1     10               6       1000  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
# 10       1     11               7       1000  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
# 11       1     12               8       1000  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
# 12       1     13               9        500   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 13       1     13              10        500   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 14       1     13              11        500   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 15       1     13              12        500   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 
# $`2`
#    RiverID SiteID Upstream_SiteID Dist2Mouth route1 route2 route3 route4
# 16       2      2               1       2000   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
# 17       2      3               1       2000  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
# 18       2      4               1       2000  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
# 19       2      5               2       1500   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# 20       2      6               2       1500  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
# 21       2      7               3       1500  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
# 22       2      8               4       1500  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
# 23       2      9               5       1000   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
# 24       2     10               6       1000  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
# 25       2     11               7       1000  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
# 26       2     12               8       1000  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
# 27       2     13               9        500   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 28       2     13              10        500   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 29       2     13              11        500   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
# 30       2     13              12        500   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
```

I didn't much like the idea of duplicating the rows for points located on more than one route so I rather added a logical column for each route instead. You can change that if you like, the routes are available inside the `lapply` in the `routes` variable which looks like this:

```r
# [[1]]
# [1] "13" "9"  "5"  "2"  "1" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "13" "10" "6"  "2"  "1" 
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "13" "11" "7"  "3"  "1" 
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "13" "12" "8"  "4"  "1"
```

Comment: Many thanks for this Robert, it looks to be exactly what I'm after. But I'm getting an error when I run it:

"Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors"

Do you know how to fix this sorry?

Comment: Which part of code produces this error? On what data?

Comment: It occurs when applying the 'river.routes' function. And I'm basing it on the same df as pasted within the question. Thank you

Comment: I see, it is the formula specification in `split`. It only works in recent versions of R (4.1.1 and later I guess). Please try it now.

Answer (score 2):

The core function you want with `igraph` is `all_simple_paths` which will give you a list of paths/routes. To create a graph, you need unique ids, so I'm just ignoring the second river piece.

```r
library(igraph)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df_w1 <- data.frame(
    SiteID = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,13,13,13), 
    Upstream_SiteID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
    Dist2Mouth = c(2000,2000,2000,1500,1500,1500,1500,1000,1000,1000,1000,500,500,500,500)
  ) 

paths <- graph_from_data_frame(df_w1) |> # create graph object 
  all_simple_paths("13", "1") |>  # enumerate paths
  map(~attr(.x, "names") |> as.integer()) |>  # get the labels and not internal ids
  print()
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 13  9  5  2  1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 13 10  6  2  1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 13 11  7  3  1
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 13 12  8  4  1
```

For your purposes then you can enumerate the routes each segment belongs to and then join back to the original data (as not to lose the metadata). Iterate through the segments and check to see if both sites are in each of the paths.

```r
# assume less than 26 routes
codingList <- map2_dfr(
  df_w1$SiteID, df_w1$Upstream_SiteID,
  \(from, to) tibble(
    SiteID = from, 
    Upstream_SiteID = to, 
    Route = LETTERS[map_lgl(paths, \(p) all(c(from, to) %in% p)) |> which()]
  )
) |> 
  print()
#> # A tibble: 16 × 3
#>    SiteID Upstream_SiteID Route
#>     <dbl>           <dbl> <chr>
#>  1      2               1 A    
#>  2      2               1 B    
#>  3      3               1 C    
#>  4      4               1 D    
#>  5      5               2 A    
#>  6      6               2 B    
#>  7      7               3 C    
#>  8      8               4 D    
#>  9      9               5 A    
#> 10     10               6 B    
#> 11     11               7 C    
#> 12     12               8 D    
#> 13     13               9 A    
#> 14     13              10 B    
#> 15     13              11 C    
#> 16     13              12 D

df_w1 |> 
  left_join(codingList, by = c("SiteID", "Upstream_SiteID")) 
#>    SiteID Upstream_SiteID Dist2Mouth Route
#> 1       2               1       2000     A
#> 2       2               1       2000     B
#> 3       3               1       2000     C
#> 4       4               1       2000     D
#> 5       5               2       1500     A
#> 6       6               2       1500     B
#> 7       7               3       1500     C
#> 8       8               4       1500     D
#> 9       9               5       1000     A
#> 10     10               6       1000     B
#> 11     11               7       1000     C
#> 12     12               8       1000     D
#> 13     13               9        500     A
#> 14     13              10        500     B
#> 15     13              11        500     C
#> 16     13              12        500     D
```